# Specify a single address for a self-hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a self-hosted WCF service written that needs to run on one specific address on a machine with multiple addresses.  To that end, I have written the config so that the address to use is specified in the endpoint:

```
<endpoint address="http://A.B.C.D:8000/MyService" binding="webHttpBinding" name="MyServiceEndpoint" behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" contract="IMyServiceInterface" />
```

When I run this app and start the service, it is running on ALL addresses rather than the one specified.  I tried moving the address into the baseAddress field and leave the endpoint address blank, but got the exact same result.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, for anyone else who happens to run into this problem, it isn't with the service configuration, it's with the binding configuration.

The `webHttpBinding` binding has a `hostNameComparisonMode` property that defaults to `StrongWildcard`.

This means that an http service ignores the host name and responds to any hostname.  As a side effect, it runs on all open addresses on the machine.

If this value is changed to Exact, then it uses the host name or IP address specified either in the endpoint or the base address.